# Литература по составлению шаблонов для регулярных выражений

Tags: php

Уважаемые пользователи SO, можете посоветовать(возможно из вашего опыта), где можно почитать про составление шаблонов для регулярных выражений(`preg_match`)? Постоянно вижу как тут составляют сложные шаблоны, а из примеров найденных в интернете у меня даже более-менее простой не получилось собрать. Заранее всем благодарен за ответ!

Comment: В метку зайдите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скачайте 3-е издание Джеффри Фридла "Регулярные выражения". Там раскрываются все тонкости этого мощного инструмента.